# Probability density function constant

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

If we have a density function $f(x,y)=cxy(x+y)$ where $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$. How would you figure out what the constant $c$ is? I am not completely sure, but what I am thinking is, since it is defined on those intervals, and the probability has to sum to $1$. We have that $$P(0 < X < 1, 0 < Y < 1)=\int_0^1\int_0^1cxy(x+y) dx dy = 1.$$

Comment: That's right. The constant is always the inverse of the (double here) integral.